# Azure SharedKeyCredentials fails with Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit

Tags: azure-storage, azure-java-sdk

While trying to run the simple example from [Storage-blobs-java-v10-quickstart](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-java-v10-quickstart) and using the reference listed in [API reference document](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._service_u_r_l.serviceurl?view=azure-java-preview#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob__service_u_r_l_ServiceURL_URL_HttpPipeline_) as:

```
String accountName = "acsazurestore";
String accountKey = "qjC6s44AmSbAkJ7Xqdsks/jjZDIYRTY8qg...."; [not the full one]

SharedKeyCredentials sharedKeyCredentials = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
```

While compiling (`mvn compile exec:java`), the program fails with the below error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:704)
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.SharedKeyCredentials.<init>(SharedKeyCredentials.java:60)
at quickstart.Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:162)
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks like you entered invalid storage account key. Where did you get it?

Comment: i masked the keys as 'xxx', i'm using the actual keys though.

Answer (score 1):

It should work even with a fake account key. I assume that it may occur in the other code line.
If it is not that case. I recommend that you could create a new project and add the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>

        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>

        <version>10.1.0</version>

</dependency>
```

And just add the following code and test again.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        String accountName = "accountName";
        String accountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

        try {
            SharedKeyCredentials sharedKeyCredentials = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
            System.out.print(sharedKeyCredentials.getAccountName());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Test Result:**

[image]